# Silverlight MediaElement internal buffering

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement, mediastreamsource

I am working with an Silverlight application where I am using a MediaElement and a custom MediaStreamSource to playback h.264 frames. I have noticed the MediaElement seems to have its own internal buffer. The frame being returned to GetSampleAsync is played a second or two after its returned. This is problematic for my application and would be much better if that frame would be immediately played. Is this possible in any way, or is this just an unfortunate down side to video playback in Silverlight?

Comment: Even though I did a lot a MediaElement hackery in Silverlight (we're developing a signage software in Silverlight) I never implemented my own MediaStreamSource. Can you say something about why that was necessary? After all, you can always set a memory or file stream which get played immediately - unless of course you need some form of streaming.

Comment: Thinking of it, it's probably possible to get streaming also by implementing your own Stream. So I'm still wondering why you implemented your own MediaStreamSource.